# Denying users directory browse/list

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, folder, directory

Is it possible to have a document library that denies users to browse/list folders and files, but still allows users to read/write files? Users will open the files through links.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to implement allowing users to edit the file, but only view it via a link.

Comment: For which system? 
See for Apache: https://serverfault.com/questions/174708/apache2-how-do-i-restrict-access-to-a-directory-but-allow-access-to-one-file-w

See for Windows Server: https://serverfault.com/questions/814870/users-have-full-control-but-gets-you-need-permission-errors

Let me know if either of these help, thanks!